# Set cookie when customer logged in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cookie

I want to set a few cookies named CUSTOM_NAME_FIRST should be set to customer first name and CUSTOM_NAME_LAST should be set to a customer last name when customers logged in and delete upon customer logout.

I can set the custom cookie using CookieManagerInterface

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
) {
    $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
}

/** Set Custom Cookie using Magento 2 */
public function setCustomCookie()
{
    $publicCookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
    $publicCookieMetadata->setDurationOneYear();
    $publicCookieMetadata->setPath('/');
    $publicCookieMetadata->setHttpOnly(false);

    return $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
        'magento2cookie',
        'Custom_Cookie_Value',
        $publicCookieMetadata
    );
}
```

But can someone show me better way using js or section?

Answer (score 1):

try this link

How utilize Cookie Storage in Magento 2

> https://electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/
>
> https://www.tigren.com/local-storage-cookie-storage-magento-2/

Comment: links may not work in the future, it is more helpful to post an answer rather than a link to info.